# Error in Silverlight on using IIS published WCF service

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I am getting the following error message on a call to WCF Service (Published IIS) from a silverlight application,

"The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error."

However it works fine when i used the local (dev server) endpoint address. (Both projects are in a single solution)

Any quick solution will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and best regards,

Naveed

.......................
Dev Environment:

Windows Server 2003
IIS6
VS2008 SP1
Silverlight 3

Comment: You need to look at the network traffic first. Use Fiddler, or turn on WCF tracing.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the client side config file first.

Comment: I just changed the Endpoint address in the client config to e.g. http://localhost/VirtualDir/SerivceName.svc

Is anything else required to change?